# Static resources in multimodule GWT 2.4.0 - Spring 3.1.1 application

Tags: spring, gwt, static, resources, overlays

We're developing a new application following the structure proposed by Thomas Broyer for GWT applications with his multimodule maven archetypes.

In the server module we've included Spring 3.1.1 and Spring Security 3.1.0. We have a Controller for providing the SignIn and GWT's host pages. This module is using jetty maven plugin version 8.1.3.v20120416. In this module we've configured the client module as an overlay and added its resources too:

```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <scanIntervalSeconds>1</scanIntervalSeconds>
            <webApp>
              <baseResource implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.ResourceCollection">
                <resourcesAsCSV>src/main/webapp,${basedir}/../accounts-ui-client-desktop/target/accounts-ui-client-desktop-${project.version}/</resourcesAsCSV>
              </baseResource>
              <extraClasspath>${basedir}/../accounts-ui-shared/target/classes/</extraClasspath>
              <jettyEnvXml>${basedir}/src/main/resources/jetty-web.xml</jettyEnvXml>
            </webApp>
            <systemProperties>
                <systemProperty>
                    <name>java.util.logging.config.file</name>
                    <value>${basedir}/src/main/resources/logging.properties</value>
                </systemProperty>                
            </systemProperties>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Our config in web.xml maps the DispatcherServlet to / pattern.

We're having problems for serving the static content contained in client module when running the server module with jetty:run, in particular, when the gwt's hosted page is served, it requests

`http://localhost:8080/app/app.nocache.js`

resulting in a Not Found error.

I know how to handle this for a local resource (contained in webapp):

registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");

but app.nocache.js is a resource contained in other overlay.

My question is: how can I tell Spring not to handle that resource contained in another overlay?. I've tried with

```
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

in Spring java config (extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter) but the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Finally got it.

The problem was a Maven one only. I just made a clean install from the parent pom and everything is working now.

The final configuration for web.xml is:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and the final config for Spring in a @Configuration class extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/favicon.ico").addResourceLocations("/favicon.ico");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/app/**").addResourceLocations("/app/");
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

Sorry for the inconveniences.